# How much faster is an Intel i7 than an 8 bit 6502?

Tags: cpu

Saw a Commodore 64 recently and it got me wondering how much faster current desktop computers than the 8 bit machines we had in the 80s.

Does anyone know approximately how much faster an i7 than the 6510(6502) processor at integer calculations.

Comment: You might want to talk about a criteria like flops, but this is a bad criteria when software floating points or dissimiliar floating point requirements are taking into account. Ultimatly, you should choose a criteria.

Comment: Yep.  Integer calculations.  As I remember the 6510 being pretty sluggish at floating point!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/31363053/224132 and the comments on it for discussion of how it matters a LOT what kind of workload you're talking about.  If you want to make 6502 look even worse, consider a task with a large working set in memory, that would require working with segments for all pointers.  Almost any modern workload wouldn't fit in a single segment, but that's not really a fair comparison.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructions_per_second conveniently has values for both:

- MOS Technology 6502: 0.500 MIPS at 1 MHz
- Intel Core i7 Extreme Edition 3960X (Hex core): 177,730 MIPS at 3.33 GHz

So it's about 250,000 times faster. Note that this doesn't translate into UI responsiveness, as you're also running much more software.

Comment: This also doesn't account for the difference in register widths. Each instruction on a 6502 can manipulate an 8-bit quantity while each instruction on a Core i7 can manipulate a 64-bit quantity. (Or even larger ones due to SSE, but not with full generality.) Saying it's about half a million times faster overall is not unrealistic.

Comment: Well, the question is inherently vague; as you say, SSE, or the modern PC may come with a graphics card capable of millions of theoritical MIPS. Ultimately you have to pick a benchmark.

Comment: Ah, the memory of a C64 with 980 kiloHertz 6510 :)  (0.98Mhz)

Comment: This also doesn't account for increased bitwidth, additional registers, the MMU and things like the TLB and cache hierarchy, superscalar architecture, register renaming, branch prediction, instruction reordering, other optimizations, FPU subsystem, MMX/SSE, power management, and probably 50 other things.  It's very hard to know how much an Intel chip does per CPU cycle (which is "as much as possible") - it's not neatly defined like on the 6502 and for Intel CPUs probably hasn't been since the 8088 or even the 8080.

Comment: In FLOPS, a 1 MHz 6502 could be estimated at 25 kFLOPS (40 cycle/FLOP) while that Sandy Bridge hexacore (3.6 GHz turbo) should come close to 350 GFLOPS (16 FLOP/cycle using AVX) - a factor of 14 million. 2021 enthusiast desktop CPUs exceed 2 TFLOPS, GPUs 35 TFLOPS.